# How to check who has RESET the Identity column value on a table in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity

A table was running with identity value in 100s few days back. When I inserted a new record suddenly it picked 1106 as value. Need to know who has reset the identity value on that table. Don't think there is a possibility of insertions and deletions on this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`identity` columns [do not guarantee perfectly incremental values](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/668042/sql-server-2012-auto-identity-column-value-jump-is) on every `insert`.  It is most likely that no one has touched your table.  If you are relying on this value being incremental, you should read up on the specs and redesign your database.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that article am able to reproduce. In SQL 2012 identity column value gets incremented by 999 if its an int after restart.